# How to add frames to a flash movie using Flex SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm new to Flash authoring and just started using the `mxmlc` Flex SDK tool to compile MXML and ActionScript3 sources into a swf file.

I've been able to compile and run some examples and tests; now I want to define multiple frames for my movie and attach objects to them frames, e.g. sprites, sounds, etc.

How do I add frames using only MXML and ActionScript 3? If this isn't possible, what do I need to do to create frames?

Comment: I hate to say it, but RTD: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/index.html. (Yes, that's the index. That's exhaustive, so start digging. :D ) Also, you'll want to read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help to understand what is expected of you in answering questions. Some research before posting is one of those things.

Comment: I do not need to become an expert on flex, but if you tell me where in the docs is the topic of my interest i will thank you and read it. The other thing that you say I do not understand what you mean,, sorry.

Comment: The second part? That refers to the fact that StackOverflow is not a forum, but a special kind of community, and we have some unique rules about questions. One of them is that you need to do research before posting (Google is a wonderful thing.)

Comment: As to a specific part of the documentation, I really can't say. I don't know enough about what you're trying to do. There is a search bar at the top of the documentation link. Also, this might be useful to you (top result in Google): http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.edu.html

Comment: Ok. Hopefully someone will help.

Comment: Clapas, if you edit your question to describe exactly what you need, and what is going on, someone might. Otherwise, again, you're liable to have the question closed. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I only need to know how frames are added to a movie. I know the rest to do the job because i have been researching all day long and cannot figure out.

Comment: Okay, I've edited your question to reflect that. (Previously, as I said, it was too broad). You can edit further if you want (click the edit button below your question.)

Comment: I edited it at the same time

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I've written a lot of Flex apps in my time, but I've never needed to create frames manually.  Are you trying to replicate a Timeline-based workflow from Flash Pro?

Comment: Hi Brian, I do not know what a Timeline-based workflow from Flash Pro is. You say you never needed to create frames manually, so how did you create them then? I do not need to create them manually neither, just need to create them. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically possible - it's essentially never done from a Flex point of view. But because Flex sits on top of the Flash Player stack it is still governed by the rules of what Flash originally started out as - as is still used for - an animation tool.

Flash is the primary tool you want to use if you need to manually add frames/scenes (as part of an animation sequence. Here you can also attach timeline code (the old school "AS2"ish way), or associate a class that needs to be bound to a particular graphic / movieclip from the library.

For strictly Flex based applications (data centric UI) the compiler automatically generates a 3-part frame sequence to handle the original FP problem of running/starting frame code before total assets are loaded.

The technical:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html

It's a compiler option under frames - however you really do need to know what your doing to work with this.

From what I can understand of what you're trying to do: "*attach objects to the frames*", again - this is the Flash perspective. With Flex any graphical element is declared in code with a **new** operator, and attached to the "current timeline" via addChild / addElement of a DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: So it was a compiler option! Great! Thank you very much Mike, you set me on the track. Cheers!